# Component in title of react-navigation navigationOptions, can't access redux properties

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have a `<TextElement>` component that displays different static text based on the language that is set. The multi language text JSON and current language is set in the Redux store.

I would like this `<TextElement>` component to work in the header for page title, ie in `navigationOptions`. However `this.props.texts` or `this.props.language` are undefined which is what would normally be used in the component. I tried the solutions on [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/313) to no avail.

```
class PreviousBookingsList extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = function (props) {
        return {
            title: <TextElement textId={2} texts={this.props.texts} language={this.props.language} />,
            headerRight: <Icon name="menu" color='#fff' iconStyle={styles.menuIcon} underlayColor='transparent'
                               size={30} onPress={() => props.navigation.openDrawer()}/>
        }
    };

    render() {
        const data = this.props.data;

        const villaList = data.PreviousBookings.map(function(villa) {
            return (
                <Villa key={villa.VillaName} {...villa} />
            );
        });

        return (
            <View style={styles.mainBg}>
                <ScrollView>
                    {villaList}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        texts: state.textsReducer.texts,
        data: state.dataReducer.data,
        language: state.languageReducer.language
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PreviousBookingsList);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can't access to `this` inside static functions. `props` argument is passed to the function. Try using `props.text` rather than `this.props.text`

Comment: It worked - thanks so much for pointing it out... can't believe I missed that.